# Unravel by multi-index/group

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array and corresponding row and column indices:

```
mat = np.array([[0, 1, 2], 
                [3, 4, 5], 
                [6, 7, 8]])

row_idx = np.array([0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0,
                    1, 1, 1])

col_idx = np.array([0, 1, 2,
                    0, 1, 2,
                    0, 1, 2])
```

I would like to unravel the matrix by the groups specified in row_idx and col_idx:

```
result = np.array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

**I can do this with numpy_groupies.aggregate(), but can have weird return values:**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_groupies as npg

mat = np.array([[0, 1, 2], 
                [3, 4, 5], 
                [6, 7, 8]])

row_idx = np.array([0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0,
                    1, 1, 1])

col_idx = np.array([0, 1, 2,
                    0, 1, 2,
                    0, 1, 2])


result = npg.aggregate(group_idx=np.vstack([row_idx, col_idx]), a=mat.reshape(-1), func='array')

Produces: 

[[array([0, 3]) array([1, 4]) array([2, 5])]
 [array([6]) array([7]) array([8])]]
```

I have tried aggregate() from the numpy_groupies package, but it is both slow and returns an array combining np.arrays and can also include ints rather than arrays in certain cirumstances (which makes further manipulation difficult and slow).

**Why ravel doesn't work**

The problem with ravel is that it does not generalise to where the matrix has areas that are grouped by rows and other areas by columns based on the row_idx and col_idx. There can be a combination of both row and column grouping.

Comment: try `ravel` with `order='F'`.  Or transpose followed by ravel

Comment: ravel with 'F' does not generalise to cases when the group index is rows, or there is a combination of rows and columns in the group

Comment: The role played by the idx arrays is unclear.

Comment: hi hpaulj - I've simplified the second example. The row_idx and col_idx group the elements.

Comment: It sounds like you have working code to do this using the `numpy_groupies` library, but it's just slow. Can you post the solution, and people can come up with an optimized version? I've read this question a few times, and I don't understand how the result lines up with the description of what you want the algorithm to do.

Comment: hi nick - thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question with the numpy_groupies function that gives the expected result

Comment: `np.hstack(result.ravel().tolist())` flattens your (2,3) object dtype `result`.   I don't know anything about this `npg` module, so can't comment on how or why it produces such an array from the `idx` array.  I'd recommend taking my suggestion step by step (starting from the inside of course!) to see what's happening.  edit - the `tolist()` step isn't needed.  `hstack` is just as happy with a 1d array as with a list.  In either case the arrays it joins should be 1d (or scalar).